# Punctuation in a series of verb phrases

Tags: punctuation, lists, semicolons

> A youngster literally pulls himself up by his bootstraps; finds a hero; establishes a dream; and then goes for it.

Is a semicolon the correct punctuation here?

Comment: How does a person 'literally pull themselves up by their bootstraps'? This seems like yet another depreciated use of the term 'literally'.

Comment: You can use a semicolon. A comma. A period. All are equally correct; not all have the same effect. What effect *are* you aiming for? What is the context, the audience, the register? Speaking of which, the word choice is all over the map. The four list items are not really from the same book. So arguably, every which way you punctuate it, it will just stay awkward.

Comment: @WS2 - Maybe the youngster isn't wearing the boots at the time.

Comment: @WS2 "literally" now also means "figuratively": http://www.telegraph.co.uk/education/10240917/Uproar-as-OED-includes-erroneous-use-of-literally.html

Comment: @nxx An example not found there being 'At that restaurant, the Korean meat balls are quite literally the dog's bollocks'. (You may not be aware of the British slang, but 'd.b.' refers to something that is utterly champion!)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a comma instead.

> A youngster literally pulls himself up by his bootstraps, finds a
>   hero, establishes a dream, and then goes for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **comma**.

If you have a series of items, and one or more of those items has, itself, a comma, then use semicolons. And no need to remove "and". For example:

> A hamster pulls itself up by its bootstraps; finds a hero, male or female; establishes a dream; and then goes for it.

Here, the item `finds a hero, male or female`, contains a comma.

IOW, start with commas; use semicolons if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon would be fine if you left out the "and".